# How to change color of a certain string in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, font-lock

Let's say I want all words "bad" be red (#ff0000).

What should I add to init.el so the color of the string/word "bad" will turn red in all modes whether it is org mode or some other mode into this:

```
https://i.imgur.com/7WMwG1s.png
```

I would like to do it in every file I have open and if possible it should be real time without any manual evaluation etc.

Is it possible to achieve in Emacs without installing any plugin?

Answer (score 3):

You can define a globalized minor mode that will be active in all your buffers quite easily, eg.

```
(defconst my-font-lock-keywords '(("\\_<bad\\_>" . font-lock-warning-face)))

(define-minor-mode my-font-lock-mode ""
  :init-value nil
  :lighter ""
  (if my-font-lock-mode
      (font-lock-add-keywords nil my-font-lock-keywords)
    (font-lock-remove-keywords nil my-font-lock-keywords))
  (font-lock-flush))

(define-global-minor-mode my-font-lock-global-mode my-font-lock-mode
  (lambda () (my-font-lock-mode)))
```

Then, activate it with <kbd>M-x</kbd> `my-font-lock-global-mode` (or in your init)

Answer (score 1):

There is already a package called `hl-todo` (https://github.com/tarsius/hl-todo).  You can configure which keywords are highlighted and which colors with `hl-todo-keyword-faces`).  You can configure which modes it's active in with either mode hooks or `hl-todo-activate-in-modes`.